# Is $x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Define
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0\\
0 & \mbox{if } x = 0. \end{cases} $$
Is g of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$.

My attempt:-To show that $g$ is bounded variation its enough to show that its Lipschitz since  class of Lipschitz is inside class of bounded variation . its clear that $g$ is continuous on
$[-1,1]$ and  we have $g^{\prime}(x)=2x\cos(1/x)+\sin(1/x)$. in addition we have $|g^{\prime}(x)|\le 3$ for  $-1<x<1$. that is the upper and lower derivatives are bounded on $(-1,1)$ hence $g$ is Lipschitz hence  its bounded variation.

My Concern:- I am not sure that the derivatives   of the function g(x) is exist at 0. any help and suggestion ?

Comment: Look at the difference quotient, $$\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = \frac{x^2\cos \frac1x}{x}.$$ Does the limit for $x\to 0$ exist? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative $g'$ exists on $[-1,1]$, $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} h\cos(\frac{1}{h}) = 0$.